# Merge two projects into a single one

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4.5

I have `two different projects` with some of the files(xibs,.h,.m)same names but a differnt bit of code.Not entirely different.`I would like to use the functionality of second project in first project`.I have gone through google but couldn't find what's the way to merge two projects instead of copy paste the whole code needed.The concept is `when  a button in first project is clicked then it has to redirect to second project's some view`.How  can I make it possible.?How in ios is maintaining two packages in same project like in android?
Any Ideas/suggestions would be highly appreciable....

Comment: Are these two projects for two separate apps? Not clear on why you are trying to do this? Are you trying to launch one app from another?

Comment: Yes these two projects are two separate apps.I need then functionality of one app in the other.So when I need the functionality as I said when a button is clicked it should load the other app(go to some view of other app).

Comment: Are they going to be installed as two separate apps on a user's device?

Answer (score 0):

you should copy one of your project file into another project this is your solution..